# Conditions for $A \times B$ to be countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both sets, and $B$ is for sure **countably infinite**. What are the conditions that $A$ must have so that $A\times B$ is **countable**? The possible answers (I suspect more than one is true) are

1. necessary that $A$ is countably infinite
2. necessary that $A$ is just countable
3. sufficient that $A$ is countably infinite
4. sufficient that $A$ is just countable

I don't quite understand the difference between "necessary" and "sufficient", and I'm also not quite clear on how being **countable** vs **countably infinite** changes the problem.

For example, I know that if $A, B$ are both countably infinite, $A\times B$ is countably infinite. But does that mean that the fact that $A$ is countably infinite is "necessary" or just "sufficient"? I really don't understand. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Countable set is a set with the same cardinality as some subset of the set of natural numbers. Now if a set has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers, it is called countably infinite, but because of the fact that any set is a subset of itself it means that any countably infinite set is countable.

Comment: $P$ being "sufficient" for $Q$ means that $P\rightarrow Q$. On the other hand, $P$ being "necessary" for $Q$ means that $Q\rightarrow P$. In other words, "sufficient" is short for "$P$ is sufficient to imply $Q$", and "necessary" is short for "$P$ necessarily occurs whenever $Q$ does".

Comment: About "necessary" and "sufficient". Suppose you know that if some proposition P is true than proposition Q is true. Than, you say that P is sufficient for Q, and Q is necessary for P.

Comment: To win the lottery it is necessary to buy a ticket.  But it is not sufficient; many people buy tickets and do not win.  To become ill, it is sufficient to drink bleach, but it is not necessary; many people become ill without drinking bleach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ and $Q$ are two propositions, then you have the following equivalences:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{If } P \text{ then } Q & & & P \implies Q & & & P \text{ is a sufficient condition for }Q, \\[6pt]
\text{If } Q \text{ then } P & & & P \impliedby Q & & & P \text{ is a necessary condition for }Q. \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$

> For example, I know that if A,B are both countably infinite, A×B is countably infinite. But does that mean that the fact that A is countably infinite is "necessary" or just "sufficient"?

That means that $A$ and $B$ being countably infinite is *sufficient* for $A \times B$ to be countably infinite.  In this case, *necessity* would mean that if $A \times B$ is countably infinite then $A$ and $B$ are countably infinite, which is false.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have propositions $P$ and $Q$. We say that $P$ is necessary for $Q$ if you can never have $Q$ without $P$ (so whenever you have $Q$ you have $P$, i.e. $Q \Rightarrow P$). Conversely, $P$ is sufficient for $Q$ if whenever you have $P$ you have $Q$, i.e. $Q \Leftarrow P$.

So let's suppose that $B$ is countably infinite, and take $Q$ to be the statement "$A\times B$ is countable.

1. Is it true that $A \times B$ being countable implies that $A$ is countably infinite? No, $A$ could be a finite set.
2. Is it possible for $A \times B$ to be countable but $A$ not countable? No (try to prove this!). So it is necessary that $A$ is countable.

3) and 4) proceed similarly.

Re: Countable vs countably infinite. A set is countably infinite if it is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, and countable if it's countably infinite or finite.

Answer (score 1):

I will call infinite countable sets simply **countable**. Sets with finite number of elements are **finite**.
It is necessary and sufficient that the set $A$ is non-empty and at most countable.

---

If the set $A$ is empty, then $A\times B=\emptyset$ obviously cannot be countable, therefore it is necessary that $A\neq\emptyset$.

It suffices for $A\neq\emptyset$ to be finite. It's also known that the direct product of countable sets is countable.  Option 3 is definitely correct. With option 4, it must be specified that $A\neq\emptyset$.

It is **not** necessary for $A$ to be countable (=countably infinite). If it were necessary then the following implication would be true:
$$ |A\times B| = |\mathbb N| \quad\mbox{and}\quad |B| = |\mathbb N|\implies |A| = |\mathbb N|.\quad \text{(why is this false?)} $$
Neither is it necessary for $A$ to be finite (because it can be countable).

---

In case of 2, if it is specified that $A\neq\emptyset$ then it is necessary that $A$ is at most countable i.e
$$ |A\times B| = |\mathbb N| \quad\mbox{and}\quad |B| = |\mathbb N|\implies \exists n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}\ :|A|= n\quad\mbox {or}\quad |A| = |\mathbb N|. $$

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @peterh I added some details, but I am used to different terminology, please pay attention to what I say at the very start

Answer (score 1):

> ...I'm also not quite clear on how being **countable** vs **countably infinite** changes the problem.

For a set to be **countably infinite** it has to be infinite, but a **countable** set can also be finite.

Comment: Is that universal?  I thought that some used countable only for the infinite case.  Rather like rings and unity, it is advisable to check what the author means.

Comment: @badjohn I don't doubt that some authors use countable only for infinite sets, but given that the question in the OP makes a difference between countable and countably infinite, I am pretty sure that this is the difference the quesrion is getting at.

Comment: Yes it seems so in his case but I thought that a warning may be appropriate (unless I am wrong and no one uses countable only for infinite sets).

Comment: @badjohn OK, fair enough! Thanks.